# write data from dictionary to csv by python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary as below which has repeated item name, the difference is the value of each part name. i want to write those info to csv with expected result is :

[image]

```
    import csv
dict={
    'test':['part_name','test1','test2','test3','part_name','test1','test2','test3'],
    'value':['partA','12','55','109','partB','14','54','106'],
    'lcl':['lcl','10','50','100','lcl','10','50','100'],
    'ucl':['ucl','18','60','115','ucl','18','60','115'],
}
tmp={}
for k,v1,v2,v3 in zip(dict["test"],dict["value"],dict["lcl"],dict["ucl"]):
    tmp.setdefault(k, []).append([v1,v2,v3])
print(tmp)
with open('table.csv','w') as f:
    writer_inline = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', lineterminator=',')
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(tmp.keys())
    writer.writerows(zip(*tmp.values()))
```

Comment: Structure of dict to what you want isn't much clear. The first item in dict says:   `'test':['part_name','test1','test2','test3','partB','part_name','test2','test3']`,  but where is `'partB','part_name','test2','test3'` in your df?

Comment: Thank you, i just correct the dict

Comment: Ok `part_name` value is always there in your dict's `test` item? or can it be any name?

Comment: all names in dict["test"] are same all the time, just maybe extend the same number of repeated names when there's new part . like : [part_name,test1,test2,test3,part_name,test1,test2,test3,part_name,test1,test2,test3,...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code to get your desired csv. I would recommend not to use `dict` as name for your dictionary. I have changed it to `d`:

```
import csv
d = {
    'test':['part_name','test1','test2','test3','part_name','test1','test2','test3'],
    'value':['partA','12','55','109','partB','14','54','106'],
    'lcl':['lcl','10','50','100','lcl','10','50','100'],
    'ucl':['ucl','18','60','115','ucl','18','60','115'],
}

headers = d['test'][:len(set(d['test']))]
size = len(headers)
d.pop('test', None)

parts = []
for i in d:
    parts += [[d[i][j:(j+size)] for j in range(0, len(d['value']), size)]]

rows = []
for part in list(zip(*parts)):
    rows += part

with open('table.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: It almost meets what i want except the position of rows , can you help to arrange the rows like the expected table from the question?

Comment: Ok wait let me do that

Comment: or else, you can keep 'lcl' and 'ucl' one time only ( because they are the same for each testx all the time) , the rest is d['value'] change

Comment: how you want it?  I can do as your csv in your question without changing much code

Comment: it is ok, you can do as the table. thanks in advance

Comment: Should be fixed. Check now.